# Multiple forms, child form is stuck behind main form

Tags: c#, forms

As the title suggests, I have two forms, when I run the app the main form is not minimizable or moveable. The second form is stuck behind the main, even if I maximize it. The main form will still be in front. Am I guessing there is a setting I need to change? Below is the code to create the second form.

```
Reports rep = new Reports();
rep.Show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing in the current form

```
Reports rep = new Reports();
rep.Show(this);
```

Comment: I don't think that Form.Show() takes a parameter?